# What does "resource is not ready" mean in Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two load balancers. When I try to delete one I get the error `The deletion of the load balancer failed. Error: The resource '<my-resource-id>' is not ready`. When I try to add a global forwarding rule to the other, I get the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you create your load balancers?

Comment: @Vilas I created them in the cloud console. I'm pretty sure I only modified the first LB (the one I'm trying to delete) in the cloud console. The one I'm trying to modify was created in the console, and modified from the console and gcloud CLI.

Comment: Try going to the "advanced view" in the https load balancer page of cloud console. That will show you the actual resources that are part of your load balancer. You should be able to delete those specific resources.

Comment: @Vilas I can see the backend resources associated. One of the resources is the backend associated with the LB I'm trying to delete but when I try to delete it I get the error "The backend_service resource <backend-resource> is already being used by <lb-resource>".

For the LB I'm trying to modify, I see all the resources it uses but that doesn't help me because I'm trying to add a new backend and global forwarding rule to it.

Comment: @Vilas I guess I've stumped you then?

Comment: Can you describe how your two load balances are set up? A diagram of the resources and their dependencies might help.

Comment: The team responsible has identified a bug and is working on fixing it.

Comment: @RickyKazuoMiller The bug should now be fixed. Please retry.

Comment: @Vilas It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug, so if anyone has this issue, contact the fine people at Google!

Comment: This bug still persists for me today.

Comment: I got this error trying to tear down a global load balancer during a GCP [cloud networking incident](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/18016). When the Google resolved networking incident, I was able to tear down the load balancer.

Comment: I still experince this gcp bug

Comment: Still getting this issue